# How to access scripts in different Docker containers from a single place?

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

### Setting:

I use docker-compose to create a set of containers similar to the [Laravel Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead) environment, of course adapting it to my needs. So I have the following containers:

- nginx
- php_fpm
- php_queue
- app [data container]
- mysql
- sockets [a nodejs container that runs the websocket server]
- redis

[I will post the docker-compose.yml below]

### Problem:

As you can see, I have quite a few containers here that talk to each other, and sometimes I need to run commands in them. For example, sometimes I need to run `php artisan ...` commands in the `php_queue` container or `gulp` in the nodejs container.

So what I do now is `docker exec` into each of those containers and then run the necessary commands. But it is very annoying as I have to constantly switch between the PHP and the JS containers and it is easy to confuse them.

### Question:

Is it possible to have access to the necessary scripts (`gulp`, `php artisan`, `npm`, `composer`, etc.) from one place, whether the host machine or another container?

### Possible solution:

I thought of adding another container that will have all the engines installed (PHP and nodejs), so I could SSH or `docker exec` into that container and run whatever's necessary. If that's the only possible solution, it sounds good too, but I would like to explore the options.

---

### Files:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
    nginx:
        build: ./nginx/
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        depends_on:
            - php_fpm
            - sockets
        links:
            - php_fpm
            - sockets
        volumes_from:
            - app

    php_fpm:
        build:
            context: ./php/
        expose:
            - 9000
        links:
            - mysql
            - redis
        volumes_from:
            - app

    php_queue:
        build:
            context: ./php/
        links:
            - mysql
            - redis
        volumes_from:
            - app
        command: "php /var/www/koodzo/artisan queue:work --daemon"

    app:
        image: php:7.0-fpm
        volumes:
            - ../Sources:/var/www/koodzo
        command: "true"

    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        volumes:
            - ../Database:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
            MYSQL_DATABASE: koodzo
            MYSQL_USER: homestead
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret

    sockets:
        build: ./sockets
        expose:
            - 6001
        volumes_from:
            - app
        command: "node /var/www/koodzo/sockets/server.js"

    redis:
        image: redis:3.2
        expose:
            - 6379
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that you can use exec to actually run the commands? That way you can just name the different containers in your docker-compose.yml and then run a script that uses docker exec to execute all of the commands by container name.

Comment: That's also a good way of doing it, better than having a master container. But my question was more about docker's built-in ways of simplifying that task. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Notice that what you want to do actually contradicts docker philosophy a bit.  The docker way to achieve your goal would be to rebuild the image every time it changes (say when the gulpfile or package.json is changed). Executing commands on a running container is ok for experimenting but is not a good practice when trying to develop container processes. Hence - the docker way would be to run rebuild the image every time, running the commands you want to execute in the dockerfile

Comment: I understand what you mean. However, my node_modules and Composer's vendor directory aren't within the container, therefore don't affect its state really, so it doesn't seem like a business that affects the container build.

Comment: I did use your suggestion to create a script that runs the necessary scripts using docker exec, it works pretty well :)

Comment: I saw that these files are sitting in the app volume. That still doesn't change the case - changing those files obviously changes the flow of your code, and for that reason calls for an image rebuild. To make my case clear - imagine a change in one of those files having a syntax error - that would cause errors when running the command and can possibly fail the process running by the container. Take that into account when building your architecture. Anyway, happy it helped you. Have a good one.